# Dynamodb exact reason for response code 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there any way to find out the exact reason for the response code 400 from DynamoDB? Facing issues while experimenting with DynamoDB. My primary key is Topic, and PostedTimeStamp is sort key and I have created an LSI on category. Following is the command to create the table.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --debug --table-name Topics  --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Topic,AttributeType=S AttributeName=PostedTimeStamp,AttributeType=S AttributeName=Category,AttributeType=S AttributeName=SubCategory,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Topic,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=PostedTimeStamp,KeyType=RANGE --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 --local-secondary-indexes IndexName=TopicCategory,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=Topic, KeyType=HASH}","{AttributeName=Category, KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=KEYS_ONLY}" IndexName=TopicSubCategory,KeySchema=["{AttributeName=Topic,KeyType=HASH }","{AttributeName=SubCategory,KeyType=RANGE}"],Projection="{ProjectionType=KEYS_ONLY"}
```

Following is the query I am trying to run.

```
  {
    "TableName": "Topics",
    "IndexName": "TopicCategory",
    "ConsistentRead": false,
    "KeyConditionExpression": "Topic = :v1 and Category = :v2",

    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "DyanmoDB"
        }
        ":v2": {
            "S": "LSI"
        }
    }
}
```

Receiving following response... which is common for a number of errors... like InvalidAction, InvalidParameterCombination, InvalidQueryParameter, etc.

```
"Received response. Status: 400, Integration latency: 6 ms
```

Comment: The error response should have an HTTP status code (like 400) and an error message. Are you logging the entire response payload?

Comment: @Jarmod, Http status code is 200 (Ok), It is the internal response code 400 suggesting that dynamoDB is not able to run the query and not able to return the result properly even though it recieved the request and returned the response.

Comment: Where did you receive this error? from CLI?locall dynamo?

Comment: @Alex,  I am trying to query DyanameDB using APIGateway proxy. Thanks

Comment: Basically I'm trying to do what is mentioned here...https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Comment: @Vikky there should be a response *body* visible, somewhere.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, response body is there, and it is  {
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
}. Further trace of the logs give internal error of dynamo DB

Comment: A serialization exception should mean that you're sending a request body that DynamoDB believes to contain invalid JSON, so it refuses to even try to interpret the request any further, and returns this error.  This, in turn, means either the original request, or the request after transformation by your API Gateway body mapping template (assuming you're using one) is not well-formed JSON.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I have attached the request, yes something is missed in the request but not sure what is being missed. I believe serialization exception in the response  is about the error that came up while executing the query on dyanmoDB even though it is well formed JSON but some required attrubute is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate `ExpressionAttributeValues` with comma will solve your problem.

```
  {
    "TableName": "Topics",
    "IndexName": "TopicCategory",
    "ConsistentRead": false,
    "KeyConditionExpression": "Topic = :v1 and Category = :v2",

    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "DyanmoDB"
        }

        ,

        ":v2": {
            "S": "LSI"
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you,first test your `Mapping Templates` code in local dynamodb,its give you more explanation of errors.